# Using require() doesn't load php file

Tags: php, require

```
//index.php

    if(isset($_GET["action"])){
        if($_GET["action"]=="add_admin"){
            require("../gbl_admin/admin_header.php");
            require("../gbl_admin/admin_add.php");
        }
    }

//admin_header.php

    require("../gbl_admin/db/db_ini.php");
    require("../gbl_admin/classes/dbmgmt.php");
    require("../gbl_admin/configuration/passwordhash.php");
```

I have created a in dbmgmt to handle database but after calling it through index.php and submitting the form it gives me "Creating default object from empty value " error as well as "Call to undefined function create_hash()" error from passwordhash.php file. This means that the files are not being loaded by index.php. How do i fix this??

Comment: Can you post your directory/file structure?

Comment: Admin Directory: http://localhost/gbl_admin

Comment: In which directories/subdirectories are all the files you cited ?

Comment: Could you check if www-data has the rights on the files you want to include ?

Comment: just removed ".." from beginning in admin index.php no errors anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you always use absolute paths by using `__DIR__`, or for less than PHP 5.3, use `dirname(__FILE__)`

This will mean that your include should be along the lines of

`require(__DIR__."/../gbl_admin/admin_header.php");`

However, as you are using require, and you are saying the files are not being required, the only logical explanation is that your if condition is not being satisfied.

Try:

```
if(isset($_GET["action"])){
        if($_GET["action"]=="add_admin"){
            require("../gbl_admin/admin_header.php");
            require("../gbl_admin/admin_add.php");
        }else{
           die('error 1');
        }
}else{
    die('error 2');
}
```